# javascript with jquery working differently in firefox - chrome - IE

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

This script in Firefox performs at normal speed. However Chrome is slow and in IE11 it doesn't work at all. Can anyone help?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log("how much");
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('#pageHome').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' - wScroll / 30 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divA').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 35 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divB').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 29 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divC').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' - wScroll / 45 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divD').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 30 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divE').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 30 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divF').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 65 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divG').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' - wScroll / 80 + '%)'
  });
  $('#divH').css({
    'transform': 'translate(0px, ' + wScroll / 25 + '%)'
  });
```

Comment: Above script works normal scroll speed in FireFox, chrome it slower scroll speed and In IE11 it doesnt work all

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, I will be sure to avoid using this code in the future